# Why do DC movies look so dark compared to Marvel movies?

Tags: marvel, dc

[image]

Why are DC movies look so dark compared to Marvel movies?

Comment: Maybe they use that to distinguish themselves from the kid friendly Marvel and consider themselves adult oriented and close to real life movies.

Comment: Because Marvel movies are summer blockbusters that aim to appeal to the mass with mostly "good guys beat bad guys" straightforward story development.

Comment: @user10191234: As someone who watched a fair amount of DCAU growing up, I find that explanation deeply confusing. DC is already very good at animation. Why are they so intent on doing things (namely live action films) that they are demonstrably bad at?

Comment: To the close voters: this is not opinion based. There can be perfectly good answers (as shown by the currently accepted and only one) that cite sources.

Comment: If I had to close this question, I would have picked the "Needs details or clarity" close reason instead. I mean, it sure could get a better comparison than some image that seems unrelated.

Comment: I think it's still opinion based because I doubt you'll get a direct answer directly comparing the two franchises from a producer or creative of either one. Thus, anything actually comparing them will be conjecture using two or more out of context quotes. On the other hand, I don't care enough to have VTC the first time, nor to again if it gets re-opened :)

Comment: I'd reopen, except the image in the question is so irrelevant it makes the question seem like a trolling attempt.

Comment: Because "gritty" is the new shaky cam.  Everyone else is doing it so lets show how original we are by doing it too.

Comment: This has to do with uniformization to get a trademark style of each franchise. The MCU has a neutral look to appeal to most viewers (the Russo Brothers come from TV after all) while the DCEU is originally born out of Zach Snyder's mind, hence a heavy influence of his style, and Nolan's Dark Knight trilogy. A good video on the MCU style: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpWYtXtmEFQ&ab_channel=Patrick%28H%29Willems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apparent reason (and I have heard this mentioned in a couple interviews with people who have been involved with the DC films—although I can't remember specifically who) is that the first really successful DC superhero films this century were the Batman trilogy directed by Christopher Nolan, which had a really dark esthetic (visually and atmospherically).  In particular, *[The Dark Knight](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/)*, from 2008, was a considered a really groundbreaking superhero movie and was a huge pop culture phenomenon; the last DC movie to have been such a big deal was 1989's *[Batman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096895/)*, directed by Tim Burton—which, probably not coincidentally, was also very visually dark for a superhero picture.  Batman has been the one most consistently popular DC film property for decades, and the Batman "look" is still heavily defined by how it appeared in the [Dark Age of Comics](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/UsefulNotes/TheDarkAgeOfComicBooks) (Frank Miller's *[The Dark Knight Returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Returns)* being—alongside another DC release, *Watchmen*—one of the most influential publications from the Dark Age).  The overall success of the dark look of the Batman films has led to other DC film projects getting rather similar visual designs.

In contrast, the key Marvel films that set the stage for the huge success that Marvel has enjoyed in the last couple of decades had different stylings.  The first really significant Marvel blockbuster *[X-Men](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746)* from 2000, directed by Bryan Singer.  If you go back and watch that film and its sequels, the visuals were pretty dark, still influenced by DC's *Batman* from a decade earlier.  They explicitly mocked the colorful uniforms of the comic book X-Men in the film.  The next really successful Marvel franchise was based around Spider-Man, which was transitional, which kept his classic red and blue costume some of the time (although treating it as something of a joke), but the filmmakers still shied away from a bright, colorful look more like the comics.  However, with the success of *[Iron Man](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746)* in 2008, which launched the Marvel Cinematic Universe, director Jon Favreau tried a much brighter palette, including unflinching use of Iron Man's red and gold armor.  The film was phenomenally successful, and so the MCU has apparently decided to continued with this kind of bright visual style, more like traditional comic books coloration.

Comment: I thought Tim Burton's movie was kinda ground breaking in itself even if it wasn't nearly as successful. I mean, I think I read somewhere that he greatly inspired Batman TAS, which kinda set the mood for the following Batman stuffs, or something like that.

Comment: @Clockwork: Batman TAS set the mood for a whole heap of animated shows that followed it, not just Batman-related stuff in particular. It arguably made a significant contribution to the state of (western) animation today.

Comment: @Clockwork As I said, Tim Burton's movie was hugely successful and influential when it came out.  I'm sure it didn't make as much money as Nolan's films, but that probably has more to do with the change in the structure of the movie business.  Both Jack Nicholson's and Heath Ledger's jokers were major cultural icons when they first appeared.

Comment: @Kevin I consider BTAS the “golden era” of Batman aside from the Nolan films. Granted that’s coming from childhood bias.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Childhood bias aside, you gotta admit that there's something more about the DCAU that you hardly find nowadays in kid shows. Between the interconnected animated shows, the innuendo and the subtle stuffs you probably didn't understand until you rewatch them much later. Remember when Luthor convinced Amazo after his speech? Or when Batman said: "Quis custodiet ipsos custodes".

Comment: @MissouriSpartan For example, there was this episode I saw when I was young, of a young girl that Robin helped. Although I was too young to understand what was being said, after seeing it, I felt... empty, like something just happened that made me sad, but I didn't understand why. 15 years later, I accidentally stumbled on a picture of that girl, and the entire story (that I didn't understand initially) came back to me, I remembered every words they said, and I finally understood why the "Growing pain" episode made me feel that way.

Comment: @Clockwork: They're still doing serious-but-kid-friendly animation in e.g. *Young Justice* (which finally got a third season a couple of years ago, and is allegedly due for a fourth in October), as well as in the animated DC films (although those are intended for an older audience).

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, but those animated DC movies seem to have, I don't know, simpler writings? I didn't hear anything about Young Justice, I'll have to have a look, thanks.

Comment: @Clockwork Batman should really have known that "Who watches the watchmen?" is a quote from Greek, not Latin.